# Open AOSP in IntelliJ - problems

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-source

I want open AOSP in IntelliJ, I do step by step like here: https://shuhaowu.com/blog/setting_up_intellij_with_aosp_development.html

but after sync IntelliJ(like in title) can't see classes in package, I cant't create "Java Class", and in some cases after mouse over can't see tips.
I can also write anything I want and and the program does not report an error. Any ideas how I can solve this problem?

Comment: that post is quite outdated (2014-04-27), try to find more up-to-date information. Check the readme in development/tools/idegen of AOSP itself, it is expected to be maintained.

Answer (score -3):

for Aosp you cannot use Intelleji for clearly 
try to use just for IDE and compile project with make 
my advice is VScode